# while loop not working in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, do-while

I am trying to get this to ask the question over and over again while the user inputs a `'Y'`. and stop  and return the `Event.displayFinalResults();` when the user inputs a `'N'`

i am getting a continuous loop right now. I am missing something or my layout it wrong. Any help would be great.

```
            System.out.println("Is there anymore amounts you want to add?(Y/N): ");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            char choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
            choice = Character.toUpperCase(choice);
            if(choice == 'Y')
            {
                do
                {
                    System.out.println("Is there anymore amounts you want to add?(Y/N): ");
                    choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                    choice = Character.toUpperCase(choice);

                    readValidateAmountType();
                    readValidateAmount(); 
                }
                while(choice =='Y');

            }
            else
            {
                Event.displayFinalResults();
            }
```

thanks again.

Comment: Just to be clear, the problem is that after you type in Y first, then type in N next, it stays in the while loop?

Comment: It's comparing characters, not strings, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: i am new. so i know i have a continuous loop because of a tiny problem. I have been working on this for hours trying different methods and now i am at a roadblock.

Comment: Yes @Michael that is correct. if you answer N first, then it works fine, but if you answer Y then N, then your in the loop

Comment: @Luke8h, Why are you doing duplicate code for input? for example ``System.out.println("Is there anymore amounts you want to add?(Y/N): ");`` writing twice!

Comment: @Luke8h , you could try to get input inside the ``do{}while`` loop by a single attempt. you could get an idea from my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You program asks a Yes/No question, then if you answer Yes, it enter a loop which starts by asking the same question again, before asking for the amount value.

You might want to ask for the amount value *before* asking the Yes/No question again.

If user answer No, the loop will exit (after asking for one more amount value), but `Event.displayFinalResults()` will not be executed. Drop the `else` clause, so `Event.displayFinalResults()` whether it entered the `if` statement or not.

```
System.out.println("Is there anymore amounts you want to add?(Y/N): ");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
char choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
choice = Character.toUpperCase(choice);
if (choice == 'Y')
{
    do
    {
        readValidateAmountType();
        readValidateAmount(); 

        System.out.println("Is there anymore amounts you want to add?(Y/N): ");
        choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        choice = Character.toUpperCase(choice);
    }
    while(choice =='Y');
}
Event.displayFinalResults();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using `break;` as follows:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Is there anymore amounts you want to add?(Y/N): ");
    choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    choice = Character.toUpperCase(choice);
    if (choice !='Y') {
        break;
    }

    readValidateAmountType();
    readValidateAmount(); 
} while(true);

Event.displayFinalResults();
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see with this is, your `while` loop is inside the `if` statement. Once you exit the while loop, it's NOT going to run the code inside the `else` block because the `if` condition was already true.

So try removing the else block. This will make sure the `Event.displayFinalResults` method is called once the `while` loop exits.

```
     System.out.println("Is there anymore amounts you want to add?(Y/N): ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        char choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        choice = Character.toUpperCase(choice);

if(choice == 'Y')
        {
            do
            {
                System.out.println("Is there anymore amounts you want to add?(Y/N): ");
                choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                choice = Character.toUpperCase(choice);

                readValidateAmountType();
                readValidateAmount(); 
            }
            while(choice =='Y');

        }

        Event.displayFinalResults();
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear code and compact:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
char choice;
do {
   System.out.println("Is there anymore amounts you want to add?(Y/N): ");
   choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
   choice = Character.toUpperCase(choice);
   if(choice == 'Y') {
      readValidateAmountType();
      readValidateAmount(); 
   }
} while(choice == 'Y');     
Event.displayFinalResults();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following out:

```
    public void answering(char answer){
        if(answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y'){
            System.out.println("Answering");
        } else if(answer == 'N' || answer == 'n'){
            System.out.println("Not answering");
    }
```

Instead of looping, call this method when you want to ask...